# How much time does it take for an edited closed questions to be reviewed?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

Around 7 days ago I wrote a question at Stack Overflow and only 2 days it got closed. Yes maybe I wrote it wrong.
I was looking for available ways or libraries to apply logic programming in python and that is off-topic.

I edited the question in the same day it was closed and explained better what is the issue, what I am trying to achieve and why I am thinking of logic programming although I am looking for any other approaches.

I also added an answer to the question with the solution I have done so far hoping for comments or better answers or ways.

It has been more than 5 days now and it is still close. SO I am wondering how much time does it take for a question to be reviewed.

The link to the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099308/logic-programming-in-python)

Comment: There is no fixed time. There are currently 436 questions in the Reopen review queue (quite a lot higher than normal) and not all that many people doing reviews.

Comment: It didn't enter the re-open queue: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61099308/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Comment: So does it mean it hasn't entered the queue yet or it didn't so it will not be reviewed for reopening? @rene